# AS3: Is there an equivalent type like union in C++ for actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

I met an problem like this,I want to port some code into ActionScript from C++.
  I know we can use class to simulate the struct,but how to deal with the union like the code below?

```
typedef union
{
struct { byte l,h; } B;
word W;
} pair;
```

Comment: You can handle it like you would handle a `struct`. If not, maybe you should post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not the perfectly match way to implement the union type because there is no union type in AS3 ,either in JAVA. So I use getter and setter to simulate them.
Hope my code could inspire you:-)

```
package {

public class pair {
    private var l:int;
    private var h:int;

    public function get L():int
    {
        return 0x000000ff&(l<<0);
    }

    public function set L(val:int):void
    {
        l = val;
    }
    public function get H():int
    {
        return 0x000000ff&(h<<0);
    }

    public function set H(val:int):void
    {
        h = val;
    }

    public function get W():int
    {
        return 0x0000ff00&(h<<8)|0x000000ff&(l<<0);
    }

    public function set W(val:int):void
    {
        l = ((0x000000ff&val)>>0);
        h = ((0x0000ff00&val)>>8);
    }
}
}
```